# How to wrap a div containing text around a div containing an image?

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

I'm currently working on a "mock-up" website for a class final and our teacher had us start it off on Dreamweaver. Worse experience ever.

I've managed to get so much done on it, I don't want to start over. However, I'm having trouble getting the text within a div to wrap around a image that's within another div.

The Professor did it. No idea *how* he did it.

Here is the index page and the CSS:

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
body {
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #FFF;
}

#wrapper {
  height: 500px;
  width: 1001px;
  background-color: #666;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  position: relative;
}

nav {
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  width: 1001px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #CC5072;
  position: static;
  text-align: center;
}

aside {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  float: left;
  width: 330px;
  height: 310px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 2px;
}

#column_l {
  background-color: ;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-left: 4px;
}

footer {
  font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-variant: normal;
  color: #00CC00;
  background-color: #666;
  text-align: center;
  width: 1001px;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

#column_r {
  float: right;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  position: static;
  background-color: ;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  color: #029900;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#content {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  float: right;
  height: 310px;
  width: 659px;
  position: static;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 2px;
}

#aside_content {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #090;
  margin-right: 3px;
  margin-left: 2px;
  margin-top: 4px;
}

#aside_content hgroup {
  padding: 0px;
}

nav li {
  display: inline;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#nav_content {
  padding: 10px;
  word-spacing: .5em;
}

.scrollable {
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>About</title>
</head>

<div id="wrapper">

  <header>
    <img src="Images/banner.jpg" width="1001" height="100" alt="banner">
    <nav>
      <div id="nav_content">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="disclaimer.html">Disclaimer</a></li>
          <li><a href="suggestions.html">Suggestions</a></li>
          <li><a href="signingpage.html">Signing Page</a></li>
        </ul>
        <!--closing nav_content-->
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <aside>
    <div id="aside_content">
      <h2>Calander</h2>
      <h3>November</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam id lectus ac enim dignissim convallis. Nam arcu elit, tempor non molestie porttitor, malesuada in tellus. Curabitur nec adipiscing lacus. Quisque fermentum dolor eget ligula euismod, vitae
        eleifend ante imperdiet. Vestibulum laoreet nunc eu vulputate tempus. Vivamus mollis enim mi, sed viverra mi placerat et. </p>
    </div>
  </aside>

  <div id="content">

    <div id="column_l">
      <img src="Images/poster.jpg" width="340" height="265" alt="poster">
      <section>

        <article>
        </article>

      </section>

    </div>

    <div id="column_r">
      Praesent nisl urna, aliquam sit amet rhoncus condimentum, faucibus sit amet metus. Donec pulvinar erat eget tellus mollis porta. Morbi sit amet lacinia libero. Sed mollis lectus sed mauris pretium commodo. Pellentesque feugiat, odio eu vulputate vulputate,
      ante eros ornare sapien, non ullamcorper ante erat in sapien. Vivamus molestie auctor elementum. Nullam facilisis leo dolor, eget pretium diam eleifend nec. Morbi nec aliquam augue. Suspendisse nec turpis sed metus tristique molestie. Donec iaculis
      placerat dignissim. yhjdsuligbkjrfhkbedsh</div>
  </div>
  <footer>
    Sharisa Amanda Mohammed - November.11.2013
  </footer>
</div>
```

This would be the two divs

```
<div id="content">     
    <div id="column_l">
    <img src="Images/poster.jpg" width="340" height="265" alt="poster">
        <section>
            <article>
            </article>
        </section>
    </div>

    <div id="column_r">
        Praesent nisl urna, aliquam sit amet rhoncus condimentum,
    </div>
</div>
```

And this the CSS related to it?

```
#column_l {
    background-color: ;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-left: 4px;
}

#column_r {
    float: right;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    position: static;
    background-color: ;
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-right: 2px;
    color: #029900;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}

#content {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    float: right;
    height: 310px;
    width: 659px;
    position: static;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 2px;
}
```

Not sure if I did this right. Terribly new to this site. I was googling to answers and stumbled upon this.

Comment: It might help if you paste the relevant CSS and HTML so people know what to look at. It's not totally clear what you're referring to. Better yet, create a JS Fiddle example.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, this link should help explain how to wrap text around an image: http://www.sleewee.com/wrap-text-images-css.php

Comment: set the div with the image to float right / left?

Comment: I've edited it as requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you have 2 different parent divs for the right-hand column, that is why the text doesn't wrap. What you need to do is put the image in the same div as the text, and then set float:left on the image, the text will just wrap automatically. You may also want to add a padding around the image so that the text doesn't go right up to the sides of it.

If you need the image to be in it's own div, just put that entire div(open and close tags) inside of the text div and it should have the same effect. Then just set float:left to the image div instead of the image itself.

Here's the one div solution:

**HTML**

```
<div id="column2">
    <img src="Images/poster.jpg" width="340" height="265" alt="poster">
    Praesent nisl urna, aliquam sit amet rhoncus condimentum
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#column2 img {
    float:left;
    padding:5px;
}
```

And here's the two div solution:

**HTML**

```
<div id="column2">
    <div class="left">
        <img src="Images/poster.jpg" width="340" height="265" alt="poster">
    </div>
    Praesent nisl urna, aliquam sit amet rhoncus condimentum
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.left {
    float:left;
    padding:5px;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. I'm new to this still.

Comment: You have the image in a div called "column_l" and you have the text in a div called "column_r." You need to either put the entire column_l div inside of column_r, or you need to just put the image and the text in column_l and get rid of column_r altogether. Then you need to apply the float:left CSS class to the image so that the text will wrap around it.

Comment: I moved everything into "column_l" and got rid of "column_r". It is wrapping around the image, but I now have a problem. My footer is being pushed about. To the bottom and to the right? Is it the excessive text? I am aware I will need a scrollbar.

Comment: It sounds like you're missing a closing div tag or something. Go through the code and make sure all the opening div tags have a corresponding closing tag.

When you removed column_r, did you also remove the closing </div> tag for it?

Comment: Okay. Thank you very much for your help, sir (or ma'am). As my class is ending now, I will look over when I get to a computer  How can I keep the text from bumping up so close to the image?

Comment: You are very welcome, all you need to do is add padding to the image in the same place where you defined float:left just add:

padding:10px; or however much padding you want.